# In `rmarkdown`, how to add icon in sentence?

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown

In `rmarkdown`, how to add icon in sentence?
For instance as below, how to add `markdown icon` between word 'Markdown' and 'is'

[image]

Answer (score 6):

There's a nice R package that makes it easy to download and add icons to RMarkdown documents, [icons](https://github.com/mitchelloharawild/icons). First, just install and download the necessary icons.

```
remotes::install_github("mitchelloharawild/icons")
icons::download_fontawesome()
```

Then we can easily use the icon in RMarkdown.

```r
---
title: "Example"
output: html_document
---

Markdown `r icons::fontawesome("markdown")` is a simple formatting syntax
for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents.
```

[image]

You can play around with the styling using the `style` argument to `fontawesome()` or with more complex styles with `font_styles()`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Is it ok to use custom icon ? (i want use a mini picture as icon, how can i finishe it  Thanks!)

Answer (score 3):

You can use

````
```{r include=FALSE}
library(fontawesome)```
````

(The `fontawesome` package is available from CRAN.)

And then to insert an icon:

`r fa(name = "markdown", fill = "green", height = "1em")`

Example:

```
Markdown `r fa(name = "markdown", fill = "green", height = "1em")`  is 
a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, 
and MS Word documents.
```

[image]

You can find the available icons at:

[Fontawesome.](https://fontawesome.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to use `shiny` function `icon`:

```
---
title: "Example"
output: html_document
---

Markdown `r shiny::icon("markdown")` is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents.
```

[image: example]

Comment: Thanks , how to add a  small image as icon in markdown ?