# R Markdown: How to use icons

Tags: r, r-markdown, icons, markdown, font-awesome

I would like to inlcude Icons at the beginning of my titles in an R markdown script. I found a CV template of a girl that does so, but this does not work for me:

https://github.com/loreabad6/R-CV/blob/master/CV.Rmd

```
'library(fontawesome)'

\faIcon{university}
```

I also tried: [In `rmarkdown`, how to add icon in sentence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70769677/in-rmarkdown-how-to-add-icon-in-sentence)

```
`r icons::fontawesome("markdown")`
```

What do I need to do instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HTML**

You can use the following code to add `icons`:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Author"
date: "2022-08-15"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
remotes::install_github("mitchelloharawild/icons")
icons::download_fontawesome()
```

# This is my title `r icons::fontawesome("markdown")`
````

Output:

[image]

**PDF**

You can use the latex package `fontawesome5`. I had to install the package `rsvg` (just in console) before running the following code:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Author"
date: "2022-08-15"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{fontawesome5}
---

# This is my title `r icons::fontawesome("markdown")`
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this works for html files, but it failed when i tried to knit a pdf. How can I get the icon in a pdf file?

Comment: @CST, I added some code for pdf. Make sure you do `install.packages("rsvg")` just in your console before running the code.